Convert dynamic jetpopup to a dynamic page
I have a problem that I have been trying to solve, but I can't find the way. I have taken a website created by someone else and I am having to make changes on it, so I do not know how some things are done and that is blocking me, I hope you can help me. Let me explain:
I have a carousel with a single button, when you click on that button it chooses the product that is in the center position of the carousel and opens this product (which is a popup).
The popup has been created with jetpopup as a template and takes the information of the 4 products dynamically, created as post types.
The issue is that the client now wants the popup to be a normal page and I don't know how to solve this.
I have tried to create a page by copying and pasting the popup sections, but I don't know how to link it to that single button I mentioned before.
Is there any solution to all this chaos? Please I appreciate any help.

Well what makes the carousel?  Do you have the ability to change the URL and behaviour of that button?  My guess is that it'd have to be javascript.  This is a really open ended question.  It's usually best to try something and if it doesn't work provide the code that fails.  Also, what happens if you deactivate the jetpopup plugin?  What does the button then do?
